# jquery: set title of a label to "for"-attribute of it

Tags: jquery, label, attr

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("label").attr({
    title: getTitle($(this).attr('for')),
    className: "something" 
  });

  function getTitle(val) {
    return "blubb "+val;
  }
});
```

The function getTitle(val) gives me back "blubb undefined" instead of "blubb contact_properties_list_18". What could be the problem?

```
<label class="something" for="contact_properties_list_18" title="blubb undefined">Sonstige</label>
```

Comment: Change $(this).attr('for') with $("label").attr('for') an try.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: If he wanted to make **all** labels have the title from the `for` attribute of the *first* label, yes. Unlikely that he wants to do that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right.

Answer (score 0):

`this` where you're using it doesn't refer to the label. jQuery doesn't say what `this` will be within a `ready` handler.

You can use the version of `attr` that accepts a function:

```
$("label").attr("title", function() {
    this.className = "something";
    return getTitleFor(this.htmlFor);
});
```

```js
$("label").attr("title", function() {
    this.className = "something";
    return this.htmlFor;
});
```

```css
.something {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<label for="foo">foo</label>
<label for="bar">bar</label>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but since you're doing two things, I'd probably use `each`:

```
$("label").each(function() {
    this.title = getTitleFor(this.htmlFor);
    this.className = "something";
});
```

```js
$("label").each(function() {
    this.title = this.htmlFor;
    this.className = "something";
});
```

```css
.something {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<label for="foo">foo</label>
<label for="bar">bar</label>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note that I used `htmlFor` just to avoid unnecessarily creating a jQuery instance. `htmlFor` reflects the `for` property (with universal browser support). Similarly, the `title` property on a DOM element reflects the `title` attribute, so assigning to that works as well.